# Avoiding magic numbers in Phaser.io

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework

Within the problem domain of HTML5 canvas game development in `Phaser.io`, the issue of hard-coding "magic numbers" feels especially hard to avoid. Here are some specific examples which seem to come up constantly:

- **Sprite attributes** such as `size`, `position`, etc. Hard-coding these values will cause problems on viewports with unexpected size, orientation, or pixel density.
- **Physics body attributes** such as `velocity`, `force`, number of particles, etc. Hard-coding these values will cause problems on under-powered devices, if the frame rate drops below 60 fps.
- **Time values** e.g. for `Timer` and `Tween` objects. Same as above, hard-coded values will cause unexpected behavior on under-powered devices, since a millisecond of game time will no longer equate to a millisecond of real time.

I understand the solution to these problems tends to depend on the game in question, but these seem so universal and wide-spread that there has to be some general common-sense best practices to avoid them. Specifically for game development in `Phaser.io`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things can be accounted for with enough preparation.

**Sprite Attributes (namely, scaling)**

A good resource for scaling issues with Phaser is here:

http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-scale-a-game-for-all-device-sizes-in-phaser/

Basically you can scale your game based on the device's pixel ratio.

**Physics and Time (slowdown adjustment)**

Here we have to adjust parameters within our game relative to the user's device's performance.  This problem has been addressed for decades now with PC gaming since each machine is vastly different.

Classically, you would have default performance settings and the user could adjust them via a settings menu.  This is simple and effective.

Nowadays, these values are typically individually tweaked for the user's device.  Then the user can hand tweak them as necessary.

All of the settings that are changed per device can be stored in a singleton/cfg class in a location of your choosing.